# Find the fourier coefficients of $x^2+1$

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

> Find the fourier coefficients $a_0$ and $a_n$ of $f(x)=x^2+1$

Could someone check my workings please:

$$a_{ 0 }=\frac { 1 }{ \pi  } \int _{ -\pi  }^{ \pi  } f(x)dx=\frac { 1 }{ \pi  } \int _{ -\pi  }^{ \pi  } \left( x^{ 2 }+1 \right) dx=\frac { 1 }{ \pi  } \left[ \frac { x^{ 2 } }{ 2 } +x \right] _{ -\pi  }^{ \pi  }=\frac { 1 }{ \pi  } \left[ \frac { \pi ^{ 3 } }{ 3 } +\pi +\frac { \pi ^{ 3 } }{ 3 } +\pi  \right] =\frac { 1 }{ \pi  } \left( \frac { 2\pi ^{ 3 } }{ 3 } +2\pi  \right) =\frac { 2\pi ^{ 2 } }{ 3 } +2\\ $$

$$a_{ n }=\frac { 1 }{ \pi  } \int _{ -\pi  }^{ \pi  } f(x)\cos  (nx)dx=\frac { 1 }{ \pi  } \int _{ -\pi  }^{ \pi  } (x^{ 2 }+1)\cos  (nx)dx=\frac { 1 }{ \pi  } \left[ \frac { 1 }{ n } \sin  (nx)+\frac { x^{ 2 } }{ n } \sin  (nx)-\int _{ -\pi  }^{ \pi  } \frac { 2x }{ n } \sin  (nx)dx \right] \\=\frac { 1 }{ \pi  } \left[ \frac { 1 }{ n } \sin  (nx)+\frac { x^{ 2 } }{ n } \sin  (nx)-\left( \frac { -2x }{ n^{ 2 } } \cos  (nx)+\int _{ -\pi  }^{ \pi  } \frac { 2 }{ n^{ 2 } } \cos  (nx)dx \right)  \right] =\frac { 1 }{ \pi  } \left[ \frac { 1 }{ n } \sin  (nx)+\frac { x^{ 2 } }{ n } \sin  (nx)+\frac { 2x }{ n^{ 2 } } \cos  (nx)-\frac { 2 }{ n^{ 3 } } \sin  (nx) \right] _{ -\pi  }^{ \pi  }=\frac { 1 }{ \pi  } \left[ \frac { 2\pi  }{ n^{ 2 } } \cos  (n\pi )+\frac { 2\pi  }{ n^{ 2 } } \cos  (n(-\pi )) \right] =\frac { 4 }{ n^{ 2 } } (-1)^{ n }$$

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Comment: [yea](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fourier+coefficient+of+x%5E2+%2B+1)

Comment: you had litte mistakes i edited it